# Ruby SPARQL Client with Label SERVICE

Tags: ruby, sparql

Does [Ruby SPARQL Client](https://github.com/ruby-rdf/sparql-client) support the Label SERVICE?

This question is related to the Ruby SPARQL Client syntax only (!). Here an example:

```
client = SPARQL::Client.new("query.wikidata.org/bigdata/namespace/wdq/sparql"} 

wd = RDF::Vocabulary.new("http://www.wikidata.org/entity/")
skos = RDF::Vocabulary.new("http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#")
rdf_object = RDF::Literal.new(params[:orcid])

query = client.select.where([:item, RDF::RDFS.label, :itemLabel], 
                            [wd[rdf_object], RDF::RDFS.label, :itemLabel],
                            [wd[rdf_object], schema.description, :schema])
                            .filter("langMatches(lang(?itemLabel), 'en')")
```

How to add here the Label SERVICE instead of FILTER? Is it supported? For ex.
`SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }`

Answer (score 0):

SPARQL::Client does *not* presently have support for SERVICE. Best way to determine what is supported is probably through the [query documentation](http://rdf.greggkellogg.net/yard/SPARQL/Client/Query.html).

I don't see anything in the way of adding support for SERVICE, other than vast limitations on my own time. I'd certainly entertain a Pull Request to add support. Otherwise, please feel free to raise an issue on the [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/ruby-rdf/sparql-client/issues).

There are likely other missing features that could be supported.

Comment: Feature request opened: https://github.com/ruby-rdf/sparql-client/issues/99

Comment: It now supports SERVICE now.